When we should not pore water to the Tulasi ji
I've often heard from elders that we should avoid offering water to Tulsi on Sundays, Tuesdays, and Dwadashi. Is there any reference or explanation for this practice? I'm a bit confused and would appreciate any clarity on this tradition.
